# QML font fallback search

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, cjk, fallback

I am developing a chat application with QML that will run on Windows (from 7 to 10). I want to be able to display messages in any languages (Japanese for instance). Does QML fallback to any font installed system-wide until it find a font with the asked glyph? To put it another way, if I make sure my system has at least a font for any language would it be displayed correctly in QML without doing anything special?

Comment: from the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html): _If the selected font, though supporting the writing system in general, is missing glyphs for one or more specific characters, then Qt will try to find a fallback font for this or these particular characters_

Comment: @folibis: Does it apply to QML?